# Get values from multiple arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I've got some hex colours in an array.

```
$.each(["#FF0000", "#000", "#FF6600", "#00E641"], function(i, c) {
  $('<input class="btns" type="button">')
    .css("background-color", color)
    .on("touch", $.proxy(funcNew, null, color))
    .appendTo("#subDv");
});
```

I want to pass the colour mood along with the hex value. How do I do it?

```
["Red", "Black", "Orange", "Soft Shade"]
```

E.g.: 
when `#FF0000` is selected I want to be able to pass the word `Red`.
when `#FF6600` is selected I want to be able to pass the word `Orange`.

Comment: Use objects? `[{ hexValue: "#FF0000", name: "Red"}, { hexValue:"#000", name:"Black" }]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
var ma = [["#FF0000", 'red'], ["#000", 'black'], ["#FF6600", 'Orange'], ["#00E641", 'Soft Shade']];

$.each(ma, function(a, b){
  b[0]; //hex
  b[1]; //color name
});
```

Comment: thanks. looks good. Can `["#FF0000", 'red'], ["#000", 'black'], ["#FF6600", 'Orange'], ...` be stored externally (in a xml or similar)?

Comment: Of course. I'd recommend making a JSON file and using the getJSON() function when you need it (if you have jquery) otherwise you'll have to the standard ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

can you use an object instead of a string?

```
$.each([{ hex :"#FF0000", color : "Red" }, { hex :"#000" color : "Black" }, { hex :"#FF6600" color : "Orange" }, { hex :"#00E641" color : "Soft Shade" }], function(i, c) {
$('<input class="btns" type="button">')
.css("background-color", c.hex)
.on("touch", $.proxy(funcNew, null, c.color))
.appendTo("#subDv");
```

});

then you can use .hex or .color